# Add row in RadGridview control

Tags: c#-3.0, rad-controls

I'm using RadDatagridview control, it has 3 columns, the first one is Combobox column.

I need to add new rows using Rows.Add() method in Raggridview as the following:

```
gvRadGridviewControl.Rows.Add("test","test1","test2");
```

My issue is, the first column is combobox, how can I fill the combobox dynamiclly? or even from the UI designer?

My datagrid is not binded to any datasource.

Answer (score 0):

you can populate data in combo in the **GridViewComboBoxColumn** using it's DataSource property.
when you create your columns and add them to the GridView.Columns collection, you can access the GridViewComboBoxColumn and populate it with data.